# Regex match single characters between strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a string with some markup which I'm trying to parse, generally formatted like this.

```
'[*]\r\n[list][*][*][/list][*]text[list][*][/list]'
```

I want to match the asterisks within the [list] tags so I can re.sub them as [**] but I'm having trouble forming an expression to grab them.  So far, I have:

```
match = re.compile('\[list\].+?\[/list\]', re.DOTALL)
```

This gets everything within the list, but I can't figure out a way to narrow it down to the asterisks alone.  Any advice would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand it right and you want to match '[\*][\*]' ?

Comment: No, I want to match '*'

Comment: You may use a lambda in the replacement part.You pass the match and use a mere `.replace('*','**')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a `re.sub` and use a lambda in the replacement part. You pass the match to the lambda and use a mere `.replace('*','**')` on the match value.

Here is the sample code:

```
import re
s = '[*]\r\n[list][*][*][/list][*]text[list][*][/list]'
match = re.compile('\[list].+?\[/list]', re.DOTALL)
print(match.sub(lambda m: m.group().replace('*', '**'), s))
# = > [*]
#     [list][**][**][/list][*]text[list][**][/list]
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/XwcNRt)

Note that a `]` outside of a character class does not have to be escaped in Python `re` regex.